# Access the URL of the uploaded file

Tags: javascript, file, url, input

I want to access the url of the file I upload from the browser with Javascript. Can you help me?

```js
fileUpload = function () {
        var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
        

        guid = (S4() + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-4" + S4().substr(0, 3) + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + S4() + S4()).toLowerCase();
        console.log(guid);

       
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 fileUpload btn btn-primary">
                <span>Dosya Yükle</span>
                <input type="file" class="upload" name="fileToUpload" id="fileUpload" onchange="fileUpload()" />
            </div>
```

Comment: S4 is not defined. You are missing S4 function.

Comment: At the moment - you aren't uploading any file … and an uploaded file doesn't get a URL automatically, the server has to give it one.

Comment: When you upload the file you have to manage it on the server side, put it somewhere, set access rights, and so on. Also after uploading it you have to tell the client where the file is situated on the server.

Comment: If you are talking about the path of the file on user machine, then the question is why do you need it ? Browsers will normally not give you this info, for obvious security reasons. The only case they will let you know, is for `webkitDirectory` file inputs, where you'll get an `webkitRelativePath` property on all the files in the directory.

Comment: I used S4 to get the guid address to the file I'm uploading. To load a file, type = 'file' is sufficient to open a browse. 
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
  document.querySelector('.upload').addEventListener('change',function(){
    var fileUrl = this.value,
    fileName = this.files[0].name;
        alert('Your url is '+ fileUrl )
        alert('Your file name is '+ fileName)
  });
```

```css
.file_upload {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #73af27;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0 15px;
 text-align: center;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s 0.03s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s 0.03s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0.03s ease;
 border: 0;
}
.file_upload [type="file"] {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="file-upload">
  <label class="file_upload" data-error="This format is not correct">
    <span>Attach CV</span>
    <input type="file" name="file" class="upload" accept="aplication/pdf, aplication/doc, aplication/rtf, aplication/docx">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for fake path

Comment: Note : the variable `fileUrl` has nothing of an URL. It is an string which looks like an path, but which is also completely fake (and thus of no use anywhere)